# PHP compare date without strtotime

Tags: php, string, date, strtotime

I am amazed. I forgot to include strtotime but realized that it works in any case. Why does this work?

```
    if($_POST['active_to'] == ''  || $_POST['active_to'] >= '2038-01-19'){
        $postproduct->active_to = '2025-07-31';
    }else{
        $postproduct->active_to = $_POST['active_to'];
    }
```

Comment: It compares the strings, anything abnormal? it works because your time format is Y-m-d ...

Comment: Use `DateTime` if you want to do easy comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the string will be compared lexically character by character.

- is `2` larger than `2`?
- if no, is `0` larger than `0`?
- if no, ...

Answer (score 5):

Because YYYY-MM-DD format happens to sort in the same order when using string comparison.

If you were using, say, `DD-MM-YYYY` format, it wouldn't have worked. Similarly, if you were using YYYY-M-D format (where a leading zero isn't required), it also wouldn't work (because `"2010-5-10"` comes *after* `"2010-12-10"` in string ordering).

`"2010-10-05"` is greater than `"2000-10-05"` not because `2010` > `2000`, but because `"20"` = `"20"` and `"1"` > `"0"`. The first character that differs between the two strings happens to sort in the right order.

Comment: I got it soon enough and promptly forgot about this post but astounded by the helpful answers. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compare the dates only for `greater then` `less then` or `equal` as it is a string.

As long as you have date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format only. Because `YYYY-MM-DD` will always change in increment format.

Please keep in mind about the format. Otherwise you have to use `strtotime` function.

Answer (score 0):

You compare strings. In this operation, strings are converted to the numbers. If you have format `Y-m-d`, it works well because first is year which is the biggest value (Y*365 days) then month, and then days.

Result can be invalid in some cases because of not equal values of days in month, etc.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types

Answer (score -1):

IT works because you are doing a string comparison which will work in an `or` condition, so long as that condition is true.